Has anyone found issues with using np.unique on large integers?
I have a file which at the end of it produces an array of type np.int64, A. I then take:
B= np.unique(A)
and save both A and B into memory.
When I load A and B out of memory, on a different computer, the datatype is unchanged but I get an error: there are entries in A that do not appear in B. Is this a known behaviour? Any help greatly appreciated.
MINIMAL EXAMPLE:
B = np.unique(A)

np.save(base_filepath+"/A.npy", A)
np.save(base_filepath+"/B.npy", B) #both A and B are verifiably of datatype np.int64 here

A and B are then both saved into a zip file on a computing cluster, downloaded to my laptop, and extracted. On my laptop I attempt:
A = np.load(new_filepath+"/A.npy", allow_pickle=True)
B = np.load(new_filepath+"/B.npy", allow_pickle=True)
#A and B are still of dtype np.int64
assert(len(np.setdiff1d(A, B))==0) 

This assertion fails, though there should be no entries in A not also in B.
I expected A to contain more entries than B, all of which appeared in B. Instead I found that A and B were of the same length and had non-overlapping elements.

"out of memory, on a different computer": can you explain this process in more detail?

Please provide a [mre].

there are entries in A that do not appear in B that's what np.unique does. I found that A and B were of the same length and had non-overlapping elements your code shows the exact opposite: the assertion fails
